# Python post urlencoded from file

Tags: python-requests

When i trying to post data from file

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
files = {'Content': open(os.getcwd()+'\\1.txt', 'rb')}

contentR = requests.post("http://" + domain +"index.php", params=payload, data=files, headers=headers)
```

I get something like urlencoded string

```
Content=%3C%3Fphp+echo%28%22Hello+world%22+%29%3B+%3F%3E
```

instead of

```
<?php echo("Hello world" ); ?>
```

How to post data as is in text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) closely, you can either use the file object:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
file = open(os.getcwd()+'\\1.txt', 'rb')

contentR = requests.post("http://" + domain +"index.php", params=payload, data=file, headers=headers)
```

Or you can just pass a string with the file contents like so:

```
file_contents = open(os.getcwd() + '\\`.txt', 'rb').read()
contentR = requests.post("http://" + domain +"index.php", params=payload, data=file_contents, headers=headers)
```

If you pass a dictionary it will always be urlencoded so that is not what you want to do.